# Initial width of handsontable is not well set in a flexbox

Tags: css, scroll, flexbox, width, handsontable

I have a handsontable in a flex box.

https://jsbin.com/rikufelosi/1/edit?html,output

The behaviour is very odd: at least in Chrome or Safari under Mac, after loading the page, the width of the handsontable is not correct. If we scroll it to the right, then we see the width is extended correctly.

Does anyone know what's happening? and how to fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://handsontable.github.io/ngHandsontable/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.8.2/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.8.2/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.min.css">
  <script src="https://handsontable.github.io/ngHandsontable/dist/ngHandsontable.js"></script>
  <style>
    .rb {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .rb .container {
        flex: 1;
        display: flex;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div class="rb">
      <div class="container">
          <div style="flex:1; overflow:hidden; height: 100px">
              <hot-table settings="settings" on-after-create-row="onAfterCreateRow" datarows="sheetHot"></hot-table>
          </div>
          <textarea ng-if='(selectedItem !== "userpanel") && (selectedItem !== "panel")' ng-model="text" style="flex:1"></textarea>
          <div ng-show='selectedItem === "userpanel"' style="flex: 1"></div>
          <div ng-show='selectedItem === "panel"' style="flex: 1"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngHandsontable']);
    app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$filter', '$timeout', 'hotRegisterer', function ($scope, $filter, $timeout, hotRegisterer) {
      $scope.sheetHot = [[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 19, 11, 12], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 19, 11, 12], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 19, 11, 12], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 19, 11, 12], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 19, 11, 12], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 19, 11, 12]];

      $scope.settings = {
        rowHeaders: true,
        colHeaders: true,
        contextMenu: true,
        onAfterCreateRow: function(index, amount) {
            console.log("onAfterCreateRow");
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.$digest();
            });  
        }
      };
    }]);
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is css `overflow-y:auto` in `.ht_clone_left .wtHolder`. So just add below code in css to remove it. It will solved your problem hope so..

```
  .wtHolder {
width: 100% !important;
   }

.ht_clone_left .wtHolder {
  overflow:hidden;
  }
```

Added [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kojugeg/1/edit?html,css,output) for you..please look at it..

Comment: Cool, it works so far... Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46969450/remove-the-bottom-margin-of-a-handsontable)? Do you have a solution?

Comment: jsbin added..please check

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `overrflow:hidden`  in `<div style="flex:1; height: 100px">`

```
  <div class="container">
              <div style="flex:1; height: 100px">
                  <hot-table settings="settings" on-after-create-row="onAfterCreateRow" datarows="sheetHot"></hot-table>
              </div>
              <textarea ng-if='(selectedItem !== "userpanel") && (selectedItem !== "panel")' ng-model="text" style="flex:1"></textarea>
              <div ng-show='selectedItem === "userpanel"' style="flex: 1"></div>
              <div ng-show='selectedItem === "panel"' style="flex: 1"></div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Can you make a working jsbin? my test showed `flex: 1` is disabled in that case.

Comment: Don't you see the width of the flexbox on the left is larger than the one on the right? It is more obvious when the table contains more columns...

Comment: in that case, just define size on flex itself. example : https://jsbin.com/hugivug/edit?html,output

Comment: If you add `$scope.selectedItem = "panel"` or `$scope.selectedItem = "userpanel"` in the code, you will see the screen is not split into 2 equal parts.

Comment: simple change your flex to get your desire design. you may use flex 40 for your table, flex 40 for your textarea, flex 5 for your div selected item panel and userpanel.

Comment: `panel`, `userpanel` and `text` are in the same part of the screen, they never show up together. I need them to have the same width. That's the purpose of `selectedItem`.

Comment: flex 40 for your table, flex 40 for your textarea, flex 10 for your div selected item panel and userpanel

Answer (score 0):

Why not overwrite the styles of the handsontable in your CSS using `!important`? Like:

```
.wtHolder {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Have a look at this **[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/suqeyovofi/edit?html,output)**.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, that's better. But when you scroll down, there are two scroll bars appearing, do you know why?