# Remove the bottom margin of a handsontable

Tags: css, height, margin, handsontable

I am using Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) or Safari Version 11.0 (12604.1.38.1.7) under Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6.

I want to create a handsontable, whose height may exceeds the height of the screen:

https://jsbin.com/bobevafana/edit?html,output

I realize that there is always a bottom margin below the table, does anyone know how to remove it?

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngHandsontable']);
app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$filter', '$timeout', 'hotRegisterer', function($scope, $filter, $timeout, hotRegisterer) {
  $scope.dataJson = [
    [5], [7], [5], [7], [5], [7], [5], [7], [5],
    [7], [5], [7], [5], [7], [5], [7], [5], [7],
    [5], [7], [5], [7], [5], [7], [5], [7], [5],
    [7], [5], [7], [5], [7], [5], [7], [5], [7],
    [5], [7], [5], [7], [5], [7], [5], [7], [5],
    [7], [5], [7], [5], [7], [5], [7]
  ];

  $scope.settings = {
    contextMenu: true,
    onAfterCreateRow: function(index, amount) {
      console.log("onAfterCreateRow");

      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$digest();
      });

    }
  };
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://handsontable.github.io/ngHandsontable/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.8.2/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.8.2/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.min.css">
  <script src="https://handsontable.github.io/ngHandsontable/dist/ngHandsontable.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <hot-table settings="settings" datarows="dataJson"></hot-table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: I can't find any `margin-bottom` in the fiddle.

Comment: I just put a screenshot of what I see with Chrome under Mac.

Comment: There is no `margin` properties declared on the `table` but there is the default *user-agent* `margin` declared on the containing `body` tag. These are typical *vendor* (browser) styles you tend to need to reset. **See:** https://jsbin.com/vofuveraho/1/edit?html,output

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError I tried your JSBin, but it still showed the "margin"... Did you save the right JSBin?

Comment: You don't even need my jsbin clone - just add an *inline style* to the `body` tag of your own jsbin demo, **e.g:** `style="margin: auto;"` - then update it, let me know once that's done and I'll check it out to verify that the intended changes have been implemented.

Comment: In your JSBin, `style="margin: auto;"` was already there, but there was no intended changes...

Comment: @SoftTimur so you want to touch the 7 number box to bottom? right?

Comment: @SagarKodte Yes

Comment: @SoftTimur adding margin:0 to body it's working. can please elaborate more

Comment: @SagarKodte does not seem to work for me here.

Comment: In your code or in your jsbin file?

Comment: @SagarKodte in the jsbin file.

Comment: Why not adding `html, body {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}` to your style? This will ensure that both the parent elements has no spacing at the bottom.

Comment: @Cheesy after that change, i still see a padding in the bottom...

Comment: @SoftTimur strange https://jsbin.com/vurukuzuyo/edit?html,css,output because according to this it worked. Do you have other style files that are used in your project, other then those in your example?

Comment: @Cheesy with your link, i have different margin at the bottom with different zoom rate.

Comment: @SoftTimur this is getting more strange by each comment I just add the css from my comment above to your link and press the share button. If this is not working for you I suggest you take a better look at you css files and search for html and body tags. And as a last comment check if not by any chance you add a margin-bottom to your table element or to your html or body (padding-bottom for those 2) elements using js or something else.

Comment: I think we see different things from a same link...

Comment: Based on your jsBin link, I've added `margin-bottom:0;` to the `body` and the table was displaying properly then.

Comment: I tried, but i still see different things... @yofisim

Answer (score 0):

What I saw in that demo of yours is; the default browser style (`margin`) added to the `body`, and not the table.

Setting the `margin` CSS property for the `body` can be helpful. Check it out yourself below in the snippet, or here: https://jsbin.com/qejekiqigo/1/edit?html,output

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngHandsontable']);
app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$filter', '$timeout', 'hotRegisterer', function($scope, $filter, $timeout, hotRegisterer) {
  $scope.dataJson = [
    [5],
    [7],
    [5],
    [7],
    [5],
    [7],
    [5],
    [7],
    [5],
    [7],
    [5],
    [7],
    [5],
    [7],
    [5],
    [7],
    [5],
    [7],
    [5],
    [7],
    [5],
    [7],
    [5],
    [7],
    [5],
    [7],
    [5],
    [7],
    [5],
    [7],
    [5],
    [7],
    [5],
    [7],
    [5],
    [7],
    [5],
    [7],
    [5],
    [7],
    [5],
    [7],
    [5],
    [7],
    [5],
    [7],
    [5],
    [7],
    [5],
    [7],
    [5],
    [7]
  ];

  $scope.settings = {
    contextMenu: true,
    onAfterCreateRow: function(index, amount) {
      console.log("onAfterCreateRow");

      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$digest();
      });

    }
  };
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://handsontable.github.io/ngHandsontable/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.8.2/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.8.2/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.min.css">
  <script src="https://handsontable.github.io/ngHandsontable/dist/ngHandsontable.js"></script>
  <style>body { margin-bottom: 0; /* OR margin: 0; */ }</style>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <hot-table settings="settings" datarows="dataJson"></hot-table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you make a working jsbin? It is not very obvious in the preview of SO. In your current JSBin, if we scroll down to the bottom of the table, we still see a space, especially in comparison with what's on the left.

Comment: Can you notice the difference in this one?
-> https://output.jsbin.com/kacusomimu/1

Comment: Yes, there is space in the bottom of the table.

Comment: I think I'm not getting you. Here is a capture of what I see here. No margins at the bottom! http://prntscr.com/h2lywk

Comment: OK, We see different things. I am using Chrome. I put a screen shot in the OP.

Comment: Created another bin, just in case the old one is showing cached stuff  https://jsbin.com/xesopefama/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157642/discussion-between-rahul-arora-and-softtimur).

Comment: The margins you see after removing body margins are due to the snippets style. Remove .snippet-code { padding: 10px; } and no more margins