# Flexbox containing a handsontable cannot scroll in IE

Tags: css, scroll, cross-browser, flexbox, handsontable

I want to make 2 panels side by side by `flexbox`, and one panel contains a `handsontable`.

For the following code, in Chrome under Mac, the left panel with handsontable scrolls well. However, in IE, it cannot scroll.

Could anyone help?

https://jsbin.com/toxali/3/edit?html,output

PS: in my Chrome under Mac, I also see the space mentioned in [Remove the bottom margin of a handsontable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46969450/remove-the-bottom-margin-of-a-handsontable), but let's focus on the scrolling problem in this question.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.8.2/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.8.2/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.min.css">
  <script src="https://handsontable.github.io/ngHandsontable/dist/ngHandsontable.js"></script>
  <style>
    .rb {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .rb .container {
        flex: 1;
        display: flex;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%
    }

    .rb .flex-preview {
        flex: 1;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .wtHolder {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
    .ht_clone_left .wtHolder {
        overflow:hidden;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl" class="rb">
      <div class="container">
          <div style="flex:1; overflow:hidden">
              <hot-table settings="settings" on-after-create-row="onAfterCreateRow" datarows="sheetHot"></hot-table>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-preview">
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngHandsontable']);
    app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$filter', '$timeout', 'hotRegisterer', function ($scope, $filter, $timeout, hotRegisterer) {
      $scope.sheetHot = [[5], [7],[5], [7],[5], [7],[5], [7],[5], [7],[5], [7],[5], [7],[5], [7],[5], [7],[5], [7],[5], [7],[5], [7],[5], [7],[5], [7],[5], [7],[5], [7],[5], [7],[5], [7],[5], [7],[5], [7],[5], [7],[5], [7],[5], [7],[5], [7],[5], [7],[5], [7]];;

      $scope.settings = {
        onAfterCreateRow: function(index, amount) {
            console.log("onAfterCreateRow");
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.$digest();
            });  
        }
      };
    }]);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just an observation (which you may already know or may find useful), Using dev tools to inspect the code, the actual code rendered is different between Chrome and IE11. Check the `wtHolder` class, which renders the vertical scroll bar on the first column. In Chrome, it's one set of CSS up and down the DOM. In IE11, it's a different set of rules. You're linking to several JS libraries, so that's likely playing a role.